# Reemplazar las contrabarras de un recurso compartido

Tags: c#, string

necesito retornar en una petición el path de un fichero,
el problema es que me viene codificado con los escapes:
*\\servidor\directorio\subdir\fichero.pdf*
y necesito mostrarlo de forma normal
*\servidor\directorio\subdir\fichero.pdf*
Lo que me pareció mas logico:

```
path.Replace(@"\\",@"\").Replace(@"\\\\",@"\\");
```

No funciona
He probado también con `regex.Unscape(path)` pero no lleva bien el cuádruple slash y peta.
¿Me podéis echar un cable por favor?

Comment: que quiere decir no funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path = @"\\servidor\\\\directorio\subdir\fichero.pdf";
string pathFinal = "";
var pathList = path.Split('\\').Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c));

foreach (var p in pathList)
{
   pathFinal += p + "\\";
}

pathFinal = pathFinal.Remove(pathFinal.Length - 1);
```

Utilizamos la **función Split** para separar la cadena por el delimitador **'\'**, esta función devuelve una lista donde cada elemento de la lista seria una palabra o token, posteriormente usamos el **método extensor Where**, para seleccionar de esa lista los tokens que no están vacíos.

Después recorreríamos la lista con un **foreach** y vamos concatenando cada token separado por el caracter **'\'**.

Posteriormente eliminaríamos el ultimo caracter de la nueva cadena generada.